# Reading LZO file of json lines in Spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-lzo

I have a large indexed lzo file in HDFS that I would like to read in spark dataframes. The file contains lines of json documents.

```
posts_dir='/data/2016/01'
```

`posts_dir` has the following:

```
/data/2016/01/posts.lzo
/data/2016/01/posts.lzo.index
```

The following works but doesn't make use of the index and hence takes long time because it only uses one mapper.

```
posts = spark.read.json(posts_dir)
```

Is there a way to make it utilize the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by first creating an RDD that recognizes the index and then using `from_json` function to turn each line into `StructType`, effectively producing similar results to `spark.read.json(...)`

```
posts_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(posts_dir,
                                'com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat',
                                'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
                                'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text')

posts_df = posts_rdd.map(lambda x:Row(x[1]))\
                    .toDF(['raw'])\
                    .select(F.from_json('raw', schema=posts_schema).alias('json')).select('json.*')
```

I am not aware of a better or more straightforward way.